# Lisp Program producing contract violation

Tags: lisp, scheme, binary-search-tree

I wrote a lisp program that takes two parameters, a destination, and a map in the form of a BST. It searchings the BST for the destination number, and prints (found: path) if the destination is found. If it's not found, it's supposed to print (not found: destination), but for some reason I am getting a contract violation. It's not running through my cond correctly, and I have been messing with it for thirty minutes. Can anyone help.

Here is my program:

```
(define (robot goal map)
  [code hidden for university honour code purposes]

; Test robot function
(robot 64 '(53 () (64 () ())))
(robot 4 '(53 () (64 () ())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one case in the procedure `(define (robot map path) ...)` . What happens if the `map` parameter is `null`? fix it like this:

```
(define (robot map path)
  (cond ((not (null? map))
         [code hidden for university honour code purposes])
        (else '()))) ; this line was missing!
```

It's exactly the same thing that I mentioned in my answer to your previous question: always the first case to consider, whether you're traversing a list or a tree, is: what happens if it's null?

Comment: I swear I had that in there. I must have accidentally deleted it. I stared at this program for almost an hour trying to figure out what was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to display "not found: 4" without the period? And I can't use the list function.

Comment: sure: `(cons "not found:" (cons goal '()))` <- that's the same as `(list "not found:" goal)`